WalletConnect deeplink breaks in Android WebView "wc:3cc..." should be "wc://3cc..."
Deep linking to external wallets (like WalletConnect wc:3cc.... urls) does not seem to work on Android when loaded inside an app. The app crashes with ERR_UNKOWN_URL_SCHEME

To reproduce:
A way to produce opening a ConnectKit inside a webview in an android app could be done by creating a Telegram Mini App which creates a webview instance of the webapp inside the Android App.

Create a demo webapp using the Get Started guide.
Host an https instance of the webapp, (you could use nextjs with vercel)
Create a mini app on telegram and supply it with your https url to your webapp
Launch the mini app and press on connect wallet.
Select Metamask, and it will break.

Expected behavior:
It should trigger "wc://3cc..." and not "wc:3cc..." - It seems this is only necessary for Android as the wallet connection works seamlessly on the browser, IOS, and desktop.
Environment details:
Android WebView (irrespective of the android version)

I have submitted a PR request to ConnectKit which was the primary library I was using in this example. "wc:..." URIs have to be opened in a "_blank" target on Android WebView
full issue + PR:
https://github.com/family/connectkit/issues/414
